# How to pass an array to props to a component in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, v-model

Currently I have a checkbox component that can be assigned an array of values as a model. I am able to pass most value types to its `:value` prop: Strings and Objects seem just fine--even complex objects with nested arrays. However, when I pass an array to the value prop, Vue strips the brackets and just passes the stringified values of the array.

In `App.vue`

```html
<template>
  <checkbox value="apple" v-model="group" />
  <checkbox value="orange" v-model="group" />
  <checkbox :value="fruitObject" v-model="group"/>
  <checkbox :value="fruitArray" v-model="group" />
  <p>{{ group }}</p>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue';
  import Checkbox from './Checkbox.vue'
  const group = ref(["apple"]);
  const fruitObject = ref({durian: true, starfruit: true, berries: ['blueberry', 'strawberry']})
  const fruitArray = ref(['banana','dragonfruit']);
</script>
```

In `Checkbox.vue`

```html
<template>
 <p>
  <label>
    <input 
      type="checkbox"
      v-bind="$attrs"
      :value="value"
      v-model="checkboxModel"
    />
    {{ value }}
  </label>
  </p>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  customOptions: {}
}
</script>
<script setup>
  import {ref, computed, defineEmits} from 'vue';
  const props = defineProps({
        modelValue:  [String, Number, Boolean, Object, Array, Symbol, Function],
    value: [String, Number, Boolean, Object, Array, Symbol, Function],
  });
  
 const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
  
 const checkboxModel = computed({
  get() {
    return props.modelValue
  },
  set(newValue) {
    emit('update:modelValue', newValue)
  }
})

</script>
```

You'll notice that the group model adds and removes values to the array just fine except for the array. And if you look at the source, you'll see that the value being passed to the checkbox component is not an array at all but a string. Is there a way to fix this?

[Link to SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: `Vue.mergeProps` seems to be responsible here since it turns everything that is not an array to array and merges the values `[ ...[ oldProps ], ...( Array.isArray(newValue) ? newValue : [ newValue ] ) ]` (Source: SSR tab in your Vue playground). You might want to fill a bug report here

Comment: Sounds good. I may do just that, do you a link to the source of `Vue.mergeProps` so  I can get a little more context about what it's doing there?

Comment: So far, docs mention it here https://vuejs.org/api/render-function.html#mergeprops but I didn't go into details checking github source code

Comment: Oops, my bad. Read that wrong. It's `_ssrRenderAttrs`. But, looks like that's how it's rendered, yes, so automatically. Again, if you look at the `SSR` tab when you select `Checkbox.vue`, you can see the `checked:` (Line 53) the `Array.isArray` mentioned above